# How do I capture details on a two-step form?

Tags: wordpress, forms, contact-form, multi-step

I know that it is possible to create multi-steps forms and capture details from each step and collate them. I don't know how the technical implementation works though.

I currently have a two-step form in Wordpress with WPCF7 (first page with basic contact details and a ' continue ' button, second page with more personal details and a ' submit ' button), and I want to be able to capture their details from the 1st page even if they drop off, and collate them with the second page if they do go through the second page and submit.

Does anyone know how that can be implemented?

Thanks,
Chloe

Comment: Can we see the code you have for this? Plugin you are using?

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-multi-step-module/

Comment: Wordpress Contact Form 7, is that enough info or do you need me to fetch the code from the page?

Comment: Thanks @Anand, does this plugin allow for data capture of the first step even if the second is not filled in?

Comment: You can use https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-to-database-extension/ and yes it will allow to capture the data even when the 2nd is not filled in.

Comment: Hum so here is what I got back from our developers...

Comment: Multistep Module
This plugin allows to do the common sending of the several forms (if for example these forms are placed on different pages). For instance we apply the form, then we are directed to the next form and so on. As a result the final form sends all the data from all the forms. 

However, this plugin doesn't allow to make random sending from different forms - all the steps should be more sound (1st form at the beginning, then 2nd form, after 3rd, etc).

DB extension
This one is used for saving the information filled in our data base. So that admin has the access to them in anytime.